# function in Where clause postgresql (dynamic column)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created func_leonard_test2 function which returns **teach_fra=true** when

```
SELECT func_leonard_test2('Français-Philosophie');
```

func_leonard_test2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_leonard_test2(
    IN url text,
    OUT translation text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$BEGIN

SELECT CONCAT(translate,'=true') INTO translation FROM seo_content WHERE name=url;     

END;$BODY$
```

I want to add the function in a where clause like below

```
SELECT description FROM c_users WHERE (SELECT func_leonard_test('Français-Philosophie')) LIMIT 10;
```

but i get the error 
**ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text**

How can i make the function work in the WHERE clause ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need a return value in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a string.  You need some sort of string comparison.  Someting like:

```
WHERE func_leonard_test('Français-Philosophie') IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
WHERE func_leonard_test('Français-Philosophie') = 'ABC'
```

Also, the `SELECT` is not necessary.

EDIT:

I think you want the function to return a boolean.  One way to write it would be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_leonard_test2 (
    IN in_url text
   )
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT (c.translate = true)
            FROM seo_content c
            WHERE c.name = in_url
           );     
END;$BODY$
```

Then you can use:

```
WHERE func_leonard_test('Français-Philosophie')
```

Comment: Hi, i get this **function result type must be boolean because of OUT parameters**, the OUT here might be teach_fra=true not bool.